# TypeScript : Copy objects with properties that matches

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to create a new object only with the properties that i need.

Example:

```js
interface Foo {
    a: string;
    c: string;
}
interface Doo {
    a: string;
    h: number;
    c: string;
}

const objFoo = {} as Foo;
const objDoo = {} as Doo;

objFoo = {}
objDoo = { a: 'hi', h: 1, c: 'gray' }


objFoo = objDoo // only with the properties that matches with properties of objFoo

//output expected
objFoo { a: 'hi', c: 'gray' }
```

i tried with object.assign(objFoo,objDoo), but doens't work.
please help

Comment: You can't do this with typescript, and you also shouldn't use `as Foo/Doo` because the empty object does not match that interface.

Comment: nice, and the way to solve this problem is initializing the object properties ?

Comment: You should just explicitly specify which properties you want to copy, or you keep an array with all properties you want to copy and loop through it.

Answer (score 1):

If you switch to classes and have very verbose constructors, it can be done.  Its not pretty, and I'm not sure I'd recommend it though.

Working stackblitz, see the console log of the objects: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vqs81k

```js
export class Foo {
    a: string;
    c: string;
    constructor(kwargs?: Partial<Foo>) {
        if (kwargs) {
            this.a = kwargs.a;
            this.c = kwargs.c;
        }

    }
}

export class Doo {
    a: string;
    h: number;
    c: string;
    constructor(kwargs?: Partial<Doo>) {
        if (kwargs) {
            this.a = kwargs.a;
            this.h = kwargs.h;
            this.c = kwargs.c;
        }

    }
}

let objDoo = new Doo({ a: 'hi', h: 1, c: 'gray' });

let objFoo = new Foo(objDoo);

console.log(objDoo);
console.log(objFoo);
```